Transformation of coordinates of aruko vectors
import numpy as np
import cv2

ARUCO_DICT = {
    "DICT_4X4_50": cv2.aruco.DICT_4X4_50,
    "DICT_4X4_100": cv2.aruco.DICT_4X4_100,
    "DICT_4X4_250": cv2.aruco.DICT_4X4_250,
    "DICT_4X4_1000": cv2.aruco.DICT_4X4_1000,
    "DICT_5X5_50": cv2.aruco.DICT_5X5_50,
    "DICT_5X5_100": cv2.aruco.DICT_5X5_100,
    "DICT_5X5_250": cv2.aruco.DICT_5X5_250,
    "DICT_5X5_1000": cv2.aruco.DICT_5X5_1000,
    "DICT_6X6_50": cv2.aruco.DICT_6X6_50,
    "DICT_6X6_100": cv2.aruco.DICT_6X6_100,
    "DICT_6X6_250": cv2.aruco.DICT_6X6_250,
    "DICT_6X6_1000": cv2.aruco.DICT_6X6_1000,
    "DICT_7X7_50": cv2.aruco.DICT_7X7_50,
    "DICT_7X7_100": cv2.aruco.DICT_7X7_100,
    "DICT_7X7_250": cv2.aruco.DICT_7X7_250,
    "DICT_7X7_1000": cv2.aruco.DICT_7X7_1000,
    "DICT_ARUCO_ORIGINAL": cv2.aruco.DICT_ARUCO_ORIGINAL,
    "DICT_APRILTAG_16h5": cv2.aruco.DICT_APRILTAG_16h5,
    "DICT_APRILTAG_25h9": cv2.aruco.DICT_APRILTAG_25h9,
    "DICT_APRILTAG_36h10": cv2.aruco.DICT_APRILTAG_36h10,
    "DICT_APRILTAG_36h11": cv2.aruco.DICT_APRILTAG_36h11
}

# Global variables to store the latest rvec and tvec
latest_tvecs = {}

def bilinear_interpolation(x, y, points):
    '''Interpolate (x,y) from values associated with four points.

    The four points are a list of four triplets:  (x, y, value).
    The four points can be in any order.  They should form a rectangle.

    Return the interpolated value at (x,y)
    '''
    points = sorted(points)               # order points by x, then by y
    (x1, y1, q11), (_x1, y2, q12), (x2, _y1, q21), (_x2, _y2, q22) = points

    # if x1 != _x1 or x2 != _x2 or y1 != _y1 or y2 != _y2:
    #     raise ValueError('points do not form a rectangle')
    # if not x1 <= x <= x2 or not y1 <= y <= y2:
    #     raise ValueError('(x, y) not within the rectangle')

    return (q11 * (x2 - x) * (y2 - y) +
            q21 * (x - x1) * (y2 - y) +
            q12 * (x2 - x) * (y - y1) +
            q22 * (x - x1) * (y - y1)
           ) / ((x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1) + 0.0)

def aruco_display(corners, ids, rejected, image):
    if len(corners) > 0:
        ids = ids.flatten()
        for (markerCorner, markerID) in zip(corners, ids):
            corners = markerCorner.reshape((4, 2))
            (topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft) = corners

            topRight = (int(topRight[0]), int(topRight[1]))
            bottomRight = (int(bottomRight[0]), int(bottomRight[1]))
            bottomLeft = (int(bottomLeft[0]), int(bottomLeft[1]))
            topLeft = (int(topLeft[0]), int(topLeft[1]))

            cv2.line(image, topLeft, topRight, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.line(image, topRight, bottomRight, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.line(image, bottomRight, bottomLeft, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.line(image, bottomLeft, topLeft, (0, 255, 0), 2)

            cX = int((topLeft[0] + bottomRight[0]) / 2.0)
            cY = int((topLeft[1] + bottomRight[1]) / 2.0)
            cv2.circle(image, (cX, cY), 4, (0, 0, 255), -1)

            cv2.putText(image, str(markerID), (topLeft[0], topLeft[1] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                        0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            print(f"[Inference] ArUco marker ID: {markerID}")

    return image



def pose_estimation(frame, aruco_dict_type, matrix_coefficients, distortion_coefficients):
    global latest_tvecs
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    aruco_dict = cv2.aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(aruco_dict_type)
    parameters = cv2.aruco.DetectorParameters()
    detector = cv2.aruco.ArucoDetector(aruco_dict, parameters)

    corners, ids, rejected_img_points = detector.detectMarkers(frame)

    if len(corners) > 0:
        cv2.aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(frame, corners, ids)

        ids = ids.flatten()
        centroids = []
        for i, corner in enumerate(corners):
            markerSize = 5.292
            objPoints = np.array([
                [-markerSize / 2, markerSize / 2, 0],
                [markerSize / 2, markerSize / 2, 0],
                [markerSize / 2, -markerSize / 2, 0],
                [-markerSize / 2, -markerSize / 2, 0]
            ], dtype=np.float32)

            imgPoints = corner.reshape((4, 2))

            success, rvec, tvec = cv2.solvePnP(objPoints, imgPoints, matrix_coefficients, distortion_coefficients)

            if success:
                marker_id = ids[i]
                latest_tvecs[marker_id] = tvec

                cv2.drawFrameAxes(frame, matrix_coefficients, distortion_coefficients, rvec, tvec, 0.01)

                # Calculate centroid
                centroid = np.mean(corner[0], axis=0)
                centroids.append(centroid)

                # Calculate pixel coordinates
                cx, cy = int(centroid[0]), int(centroid[1])

                # Display pixel coordinates above the marker in red
                coord_text = f"({cx}, {cy})"
                cv2.putText(frame, coord_text, (cx, cy - 15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)

                # Create a separate text area for each marker
                text_y = 30 + i * 120
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (10, text_y - 20), (300, text_y + 100), -1)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (10, text_y - 20), (300, text_y + 100), (0, 0, 0), 1)
                tvec_str = f"tvec: ({tvec[0][0]:.2f}, {tvec[1][0]:.2f}, {tvec[2][0]:.2f})"
                cv2.putText(frame, tvec_str, (15, text_y + 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1)
                cv2.putText(frame, f"Marker ID: {marker_id}", (15, text_y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1)

        if len(centroids) == 4:
            centroids = np.array(centroids, dtype=np.int32)

            # Sort centroids in clockwise order
            center = np.mean(centroids, axis=0)
            sorted_centroids = sorted(centroids, key=lambda p: np.arctan2(p[1] - center[1], p[0] - center[0]))
            sorted_centroids = np.array(sorted_centroids, dtype=np.int32)

            # Draw the quadrilateral
            cv2.polylines(frame, [sorted_centroids], True, (255, 0, 0), 2)  # Blue quadrilateral

            # The origin is the first marker in the sorted list
            origin = sorted_centroids[0]

            # Calculate and display relative positions
            for i, centroid in enumerate(sorted_centroids[0:], 1):
                relative_pos = centroid - origin
                pos_text = f"Marker {i}: ({relative_pos[0]}, {relative_pos[1]})"
                cv2.putText(frame, pos_text, tuple(centroid + [10, 10]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1)

            specific_point = (637, 423)
            cv2.circle(frame, specific_point, 5, (0, 255, 255), -1)  # Yellow dot
            cv2.putText(frame, f"({specific_point[0]}, {specific_point[1]})",
                        (specific_point[0] + 25, specific_point[1] - 25),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 255), 2)

            # Perform bilinear interpolation
            try:
                interpolated_x = bilinear_interpolation(specific_point[0], specific_point[1], [
                    (sorted_centroids[0][0], sorted_centroids[0][1], 0),
                    (sorted_centroids[1][0], sorted_centroids[1][1], 1),
                    (sorted_centroids[2][0], sorted_centroids[2][1], 1),
                    (sorted_centroids[3][0], sorted_centroids[3][1], 0)
                ])
                interpolated_y = bilinear_interpolation(specific_point[0], specific_point[1], [
                    (sorted_centroids[0][0], sorted_centroids[0][1], 0),
                    (sorted_centroids[1][0], sorted_centroids[1][1], 0),
                    (sorted_centroids[2][0], sorted_centroids[2][1], 1),
                    (sorted_centroids[3][0], sorted_centroids[3][1], 1)
                ])

                # Calculate the relative position to the origin
                relative_x = interpolated_x * (sorted_centroids[1][0] - origin[0])
                relative_y = interpolated_y * (sorted_centroids[3][1] - origin[1])

                interpolated_pos = f"Relative: ({relative_x:.2f}, {relative_y:.2f})"
                cv2.putText(frame, interpolated_pos,
                            (specific_point[0] + 10, specific_point[1] - 10),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 0, 255), 1)
            except ValueError as e:
                print(f"Interpolation error: {e}")

    return frame


aruco_type = "DICT_6X6_250"

# These are camera intrinsic properties and need to be changed for the camera used.
intrinsic_camera = np.array(((933.15867, 0, 657.59), (0, 933.1586, 400.36993), (0, 0, 1)))
distortion = np.array((-0.43948, 0.18514, 0, 0))

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, img = cap.read()

    output = pose_estimation(img, ARUCO_DICT[aruco_type], intrinsic_camera, distortion)

    cv2.imshow('Estimated Pose', output)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

When I am moving the camera then the relative positions of aruko markers get's changed. I want that no matter what is the location of my camera the relative coordinates of my marker remain same.

Now what I want is that the topmost corner of the graph paper is considered as origin and the relative postion of aruko markers must be according to that origin.

discard their rvecs. the arucos are too small for the rvecs to make much sense. just consider their tvecs. you have four points in space. span a plane through those. four points overdetermine a plane.
